# ghc-pkg: cannot create: dist/dist-sandbox-XXXXXXXX/package.conf.inplace already exists

Tags: haskell, cabal

I've just upgraded to cabal 1.22.0.0. I created a *brand new* sandbox, and added a link to another local package like so:

```
cabal sandbox add-source /home/amy/néal/créatúr-wains
```

Then I tried to install the dependencies:

```
cabal install --dep
```

But when it got to the part where it tried to build my local package, I got an error:

```
Configuring creatur-wains-4.1.1...
Building creatur-wains-4.1.1...
ghc-pkg: cannot create: dist/dist-sandbox-5cb45741/package.conf.inplace already exists
```

I get the same result if I try to install that package using `cabal install creatur-wains`. I didn't have this problem with earlier versions of cabal. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/2301)https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/2301. The workaround is:

1. Go to the directory containing the local package (/home/amy/néal/créatúr-wains, in my case).
2. Build the local package (`cabal install`).
3. Return to the original directory. `cabal install` will now work.

Comment: In step #2 it looks like a simple "cabal clean" might be sufficient.  That way you don't have to build all your local dependencies (which may have their own sandboxes).

Comment: I just discovered another case where "cabal clean" was not sufficient, and it seemed that "cabal install" was required, so YMMV.